# Django Dynamic Form Filter

Tags: django

I'm creating a web based ERP-like system in Django 2.0.
In a page, I have a form with all the Work Orders or so entries (stored in DB). 
I would like to have in the first line of the form (below the headers) a input field for each column where I type and it dynamically/instantly filter the form rows.

Example:

```
     COD      |  DESCRIPTION   |      DATE      |      ETC.
search field  |  search field  |  search field  |  search field
```

So when I type any character in any column, instantly the form is updated showing the filter results.
Which technique I should use for this?
Is Ajax the tool for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is the tool, reference Djangos RESTful API. I use AJAX and the RESTful api to handle all of those neat form tricks, including username availability, or even a validator for the input. If you would like more guidance on how to do this, I will glady help out!